# ABI interaction of Safe custom module

Tags: abi, gnosis, safe

We've recently deployed a contract to testnet for managing membership nfts of a gnosis safe, however, is there any way that we can go about interacting with this custom module in a way that doesn't require raw ABI array interaction?
At present it doens't prefill the abi array and we're wondering how to go about simple interactions like minting a batch of membership nfts or setting membership/ownership.  What's the most streamlined way to interact with this deployed module using an abi array?